# After having Administrator Level Permission why I am not able to Upload/Delete Web Part on Sharepoint Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have sharepoint administrator level permission, but after having this permission I'm not able to upload a new web part and delete web part also.

In below screenshot I have no option for **upload**, **new** and **delete** .

[image]

Is there any setting, that i have to configure or other issue?
please let me know, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to give yourself as well tenant app catalog admin role. As SP Admin you can do that.

Comment: hi @Marek, can you provide the URL or navigation for steps that I have to follow for giving permissions myself?

Comment: This should point you in right direction: http://sharepoint-tricks.com/tenant-app-catalog-vs-site-collection-app-catalog/ app catalog is basically a site collection so you need to be site collection admin on that site (or if none of the sites is tenant app catalog create new one using process described in the link)